A constraint of the form $S \succeq 0$ in an SDP is converted to the form $D^T S D\succeq 0$. Why do the rank and dimensions of D impact the solution?
I am currently studying this article. In section $3$, a semi-definite program (SDP) with linear matrix inequality (LMI) constraints is introduced. One of these LMIs is transformed into an equivalent LMI. I have some ambiguities and questions about how this process is carried out. I have also coded and solved the SDPs for a specific example. I will provide more details below and would appreciate any help in answering my questions and clarifying my doubts.
Consider a linear time-invariant (LTI) system whose state equation is as follows, where $ {x}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n $ is the state, $ {u}_k \in \mathbb{R}^m $ is the control input:
\begin{equation}
    {x}_{k+1}={A} {x}_k+{B} {u}_k  ;   {A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, {B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} 
\end{equation}
The first SDP with LMI constraints is defined as follows, where matrices $ W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ and $ H=\begin{bmatrix}  H_{11} & H_{12} \\ H_{12}^T  & H_{22} \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+m) \times (n+m)}$ are decision variables and the matrix $ \Lambda\succeq 0 $ is known.
First SDP:
\begin{align}
    & \max _{H, W} \operatorname{trace}(W) \\
    & \quad \text { Subject to: }  \\
    & \quad {\begin{bmatrix}
                H_{11}-W & H_{12} \\
                H_{12}^T & H_{22}
             \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0}  \\
    & \quad{\begin{bmatrix}
              {\begin{bmatrix}
                A & B 
              \end{bmatrix}}^T H_{11}
              {\begin{bmatrix}
                A & B 
              \end{bmatrix}}-H+\Lambda
               & {\begin{bmatrix}
                A & B 
              \end{bmatrix}}^T H_{12} \\
              H_{12}^T \begin{bmatrix}
                A & B 
              \end{bmatrix} & H_{22} 
            \end{bmatrix}} \succeq 0 
\end{align}
the matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+m) \times L}$ is defined as below, comprising the sequence of states and inputs in the time interval $[k_0, k_0+L-1]$, where $k_0$ represents the index of the first sample.
\begin{equation}
    D=\begin{bmatrix}
        x_{k_0} & x_{k_0+1} & \cdots & x_{k_0+L-1} \\
        u_{k_0} & u_{k_0+1} & \cdots & u_{k_0+L-1}
      \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Also, the matrix $ X_D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times L} $ is defined as:
\begin{align}
    X_D&=\begin{bmatrix}
              A & B
         \end{bmatrix} D \\
        &=\begin{bmatrix}
            x_{k_0+1} & x_{k_0+2} & \cdots & x_{k_0+L}
          \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Using the Schur Complement the second LMI in the first SDP can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
    {\begin{bmatrix}
      A & B 
    \end{bmatrix}}^T
    \left(H_{11}-H_{12} H_{22}^{-1} H_{12}^T\right)
    \begin{bmatrix}
      A & B 
    \end{bmatrix}-H+\Lambda \succeq 0
\end{equation}
As claimed in the article, according to the properties of Congruence transformation, if the column rank of matrix $ D $ is equal to $ n+m $, then the above inequality can be multiplied from the left and right by $D^T$ and $D$, respectively to achive:
\begin{equation}
    D^T{\begin{bmatrix}
      A & B 
    \end{bmatrix}}^T
    \left(H_{11}-H_{12} H_{22}^{-1} H_{12}^T\right)
    \begin{bmatrix}
      A & B 
    \end{bmatrix}D-D^T(H-\Lambda)D \succeq 0
\end{equation}
so we have:
\begin{equation}\label{eq.model_free_SDP_const2}
    X_D^T\left(H_{11}-H_{12} H_{22}^{-1} H_{12}^T\right) X_D-D^T(H-\Lambda) D \succeq 0
\end{equation}
$ n+m $ column rank for matrix $ D $, requires that $ L \geq n+m $. Also in order to avoid the linear dependency of the inputs and states on previous inputs and states which prevents rank decrease of the matrix $ D $, the input signal must be persistently exciting (PE), at least, of order $ n+m $ in the interval $ [k_0,k_0+L-1] $.
Using the Schur Complement to convert the above matrix inequality to an LMI, the first SDP can be written the below equivalent form:
Second SDP:
\begin{align}
                & \max _{H, W} \operatorname{trace}(W) \nonumber \\
                &  \text { Subject to: } \nonumber \\
                &  {\begin{bmatrix}
                            H_{11}-W & H_{12} \\
                            H_{12}^T & H_{22}
                        \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0} \nonumber \\
                & {\begin{bmatrix}
                            X_D^T H_{11} X_D-D^T(H-\Lambda) D & X_D^T H_{12} \\
                            H_{12}^T X_D & H_{22}
                         \end{bmatrix}} \succeq 0 
            \end{align}
Question:

If $ S \succeq 0 $ and $ D $ is an arbitrary rectangular matrix, according to the definition of positive semidefiniteness, the matrix $ D^T S D $ will always be positive semidefinite.Correct? So, why is there a requirement that the column rank of $ D $ must be equal to $ n+m $? In other words, what issue arises if the rank of $ D $ is less than $ n+m $?

Can the value of $ L $  be arbitrarily large? I coded an example in MATLAB with $ n = 2 $ and $ m = 1 $. When I choose $ L = n + m = 3 $, if the rank of $ D $ is $3$, the solution obtained for $ H $ from the first SDP will match the solution obtained from the second SDP. However, if $ L \geq 4 $ and the rank of $ D $ remains $3$, the solutions obtained differ significantly. Why is this?



W.r.t. 1: Yes, you are completely right with your statement. The matrix $D$ does not even need to be rectangular. You can find a statement proving that in Observation 7.1.8 in Matrix Analysis, Horn and Johnson, 2012. However, the question with why it is important here for $D$ to have full rank is probably more tricky. Imagine $D = 0$. Then, even if the semidefiniteness holds, you are changing the result of the optimization problem. When $D=0$, $H_{11}$ and $H_{12}$ do not influence the second LMI anymore, and the influence of the constraint to the optimization problem is different! Thus, it is also important to think on what influence has a multiplication for the constraint, instead of just thinking on semidefiniteness.
However, if you choose $D$ to have full rank, you are not changing the influence of the LMI to the optimization problem. This is because then $D$ reprsents simply a change of coordinates for a vector. Since the semidefiniteness condition for a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is equivalent to $x^\top M x \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$, a change of coordinates has no effect.
Illustrative example: Consider the optimizaiton problem
$$ \min_{S} \text{trace}(S) $$
$$ \text{s.t. } S - I \succeq 0,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. The optimal $S$ has thus to be positive definite. Clearly, you cannot multiply the constraint by an arbitrary singular matrix $D^\top(S - I)D \succeq 0$ without altering the solution. Else, you could choose $D = 0$, and then the semidefinitness condition $D^\top(S - I)D \succeq 0$ is fulfilled for any $S$, and $S = 0$ is an optimizer.
W.r.t. 2: By multiplying with a matrix $D$ with $L> n+m$, you are again changing the original LMI. You can see that in you LMI just after you multiplied the schur complement with $D$ and $D^\top$, since with that you are lifting the LMI to a space with more variables than the original LMI. Thus, it is a different LMI.

Your answer made sense, but we need a proof. Specifically, how can we prove your statement?
"If you choose $D$ to have full rank, you are not changing the influence of the LMI on the optimization problem."
You also said:
"By multiplying with a matrix $D$ with $L > n + m$, you are again changing the original LMI."
This contradicts your first claim because we assumed the rank of $D$ remains $n+m$ as $L$ increases.
I would appreciate your clarification on this matter.

Yes you are right, if you pick out those sentences, they are contradictory. The key is that in the first part of the answer (and in the first part your question), it is assumed that $D$ is a square matrix, i.e. $L=n+m$. Then, it needs to have full rank. When $D$ is not square, you will never end up with the same condition. So, to be precise: you need the matrix $D$ to be nonsingluar (square and full rank). Then, you need to proof that a constraint $S \succeq 0$ is equivalent to $D^\top S D \succeq 0$. The first step for proving that is to rewrite the constraint as $x^\top S x \geq 0$

If you have difficulties proving that statement, tell me where you are stuck :)
